# R package install

Tags: r, r-package, file-ownership

I am trying to install R studio packages. 
I am running R as a "datacleaning" user this user

Some packages are installed from the local sources:

```
if (!require("SparseM", lib=lib.path)) install.packages("/dc/R/p1/SparseM_1.7.gz", repos = NULL, type="source", lib=lib.path)
```

The others directly from R cran

```
if (!require("stringr", lib=lib.path)) install.packages("stringr", lib=lib.path, repos=url.cran)
```

This is what the installation packages directory looks like:

```
    drwxrwxr-x  7 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 base64enc
    drwxrwxr-x  8 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:11 bit
    drwxrwxr-x  9 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:19 bit64
    drwxrwxr-x  9 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:16 data.table
    drwxrwxr-x  6 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 evaluate
    drwxrwxr-x  9 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 foreign
    drwxrwxr-x 11 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:16 gdata
    drwxrwxr-x  8 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:16 gtools
    drwxrwxr-x  7 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 highr
    drwxrwxr-x 14 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:15 knitr
    drwxrwxr-x  7 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 magrittr
    drwxrwxr-x 11 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 markdown
    drwxrwxr-x  7 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:11 mime
    drwxrwxr-x  8 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:16 plyr
    drwxrwxr-x 16 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:16 Rcpp
    drwxrwxr-x  8 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:16 reshape2
    drwxrwxr-x  6 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:15 sendmailR
    drwxrwxr-x  8 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:15 stringi
    drwxrwxr-x  9 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 stringr
    drwxrwxr-x  8 datacleaning users 4096 feb  8 15:11 xtable
    drwxrwxr-x  7 root         root  4096 feb  8 15:15 yaml
```

Why is the installed package ownership becoming root? Some packages dependencies are trying to access those root packages. But then I am lacking of permission to access the root package.

Maybe I am missing something about R package installation

Comment: Not sure how you got it like this, but you can fix the ownership with `sudo chown -R your_username:your_group folder` (assuming you have a password to get root privileges)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example and the errors you are getting? All directories are world readable, so even the `datacleansing` user should be able to access them.

Comment: What are the permissions of the `/dc/R/p1/SparseM_1.7.gz` files? What `url.cran` are you using?

Comment: Thanks @dww for the suggestion, however I would like to automate the process and not have to fix the ownership afterwards. This would be the kind of error: `Loading required package: bit64
Failed with error:  ‘package ‘bit’ required by ‘bit64’ could not be found’`.  The permissions are:  `
drwxrwxr-x  9 datacleaning users         4096 feb  8 15:41 bit64
-rw-r--r--  1 root         root         28131 feb  8 16:41 car
`